# Building aws cdk-stack get 'Error: Cannot create a VPC Endpoint with no subnets'

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm creating an AWS CDK stack (2.66.1) in which I have to define 2 VPC endpoints.

I defined all the resource necessary to my app but when I try to build it with 'cdk synth', it doesn't: `Error: Cannot create a VPC Endpoint with no subnets`

```js
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';

[...]

/*** Create VPC and its SUBNET and ENDPOINT ***/

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, env.vpcName, {
      ipAddresses: ec2.IpAddresses.cidr('172.16.0.0/16'),
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          // CIDR mask: 255.255.255.0
          cidrMask: 24,
          name: env.vpcSubnetName,
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
        }
      ]
    });

    // Security group for the EC2 instance
    const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, env.securityGroupName, {
      vpc,
      description: "Allow SSH (TCP port 22) and HTTP (TCP port 80) in",
      allowAllOutbound: true,
    });

    // Allow SSH access on port tcp/22
    securityGroup.addIngressRule(
      ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),
      ec2.Port.tcp(22),
      "Allow SSH Access"
    );

    // Allow HTTP access on port tcp/80
    securityGroup.addIngressRule(
      ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),
      ec2.Port.tcp(80),
      "Allow HTTP Access"
    );

    new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, env.vpcEndpointDynamoDBName, {
      vpc,
      service: new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointService('com.amazonaws.' + region + '.dynamodb', 443),
      subnets: {
        subnets: [...vpc.privateSubnets]
      },
      privateDnsEnabled: true,
      securityGroups: [securityGroup]
    });


    new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, env.vpcEndpoints3Name, {
      vpc,
      service: new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointService('com.amazonaws.' + region + '.s3', 443),
      subnets: {
        subnets: [...vpc.privateSubnets]
      },
      privateDnsEnabled: true,
      securityGroups: [securityGroup]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `vpc.privateSubnets` as the interface endpoint subnets, but this attribute is `undefined`.  Your VPC defines a single `PRIVATE_ISOLATED` subnet, which is available as `vpc.isolatedSubnets`.

```js
  subnets: {
    subnets: vpc.isolatedSubnets
  },
```

Here's how the VPC subnet attributes map to [SubnetType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.SubnetType.html#enum-subnettype) values ([source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/3d7505b5a9c3daf5edfecdb4576b555bfe8d7553/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/vpc.ts#L607)):

- publicSubnets: `PUBLIC`
- privateSubnets: `PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS`, `PRIVATE_WITH_NAT` (deprecated), `PRIVATE` (deprecated)
- isolatedSubnets: `PRIVATE_ISOLATED`, `ISOLATED` (deprecated)

---

BTW, you are creating interface endpoints for DynamoDB and S3.  Consider [Gateway Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/gateway-endpoints.html) instead.  Gateway Endpoints are supported for DynamoDB and S3 and carry no hourly charge.  See the [Types of VPC endpoints for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#types-of-vpc-endpoints-for-s3) docs for a comparison.